# Can I use numbers instead of words in my python dataset?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, categorical-data, dummy-variable

I'm currently in the process of creating a dataset where there is going to be a large number of categoric variables. Obviously this is fine, however I don't want lots of new columns to be created when I am to convert them into dummy variables.

For example, one of my columns is called 'season' and each row either has autumn, winter, spring or summer in them. Could I change this into numbers instead? So, autumn would equal 1, winter equals 2, spring equals 3 etc. I mean changing this to numbers whilst the data is still in excel, not python.

The purpose of this dataset is to build a multiple linear regression model and I will be doing this using python. I'm just asking this question as I want to know if it would affect my results if I change the words to numbers beforehand and not create dummy variables as a result.

Thank you!

Comment: Yes linear regression expects numerical data so you should do that conversion. There are many ways of doing this and what you described is called "ordinal encoding" which amounts to say "winter is two times autumn" i.e induces a superficial importance among seasons which is not really the case. I suggest you take a look at here: https://towardsdatascience.com/all-about-categorical-variable-encoding-305f3361fd02

Comment: @MustafaAydın has some good points, there are quite a few ways to deal with categorical variables and they can be application-specific. If you're working in Python, the `pandas` user guide for categorical data also has some practical advice: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/categorical.html

Comment: @MustafaAydın Thank you for your answer! I understand I will need to use ordinal encoding for columns such as 'Season'. However, when I have columns such as 'Name', what type of encoding would you suggest I perform then?

Comment: @AlexanderL.Hayes Thank you!

Comment: RE: *I understand I will need to use ordinal encoding for columns such as 'Season'.* - No no no, I tried to say the opposite :). Ordinal encoding implies there is an order among the variables and as said, the model (which cares about numerics) will (mistakenly) think winter is 2 times "better" than autumn etc. A good case for ordinal encoding is e.g. movie ratings: "bad", "not so bad", "good", "very good". You can indeed encode these guys as 0, 1, 2, 3 and no problem. I hope I clarified that.

Comment: As for the name, if it is a unique feature i.e. no 2 sample in your data share the same name, then you essentially don't need it i.e. you can safely drop that column because no useful information is in it to help model regress / classify etc.